# Problem with negativ lookbehind in RegEx and multiple digit numbers

Tags: regex

I´m fairly new to RegEx.

I have a expression to find one or multiple digit numbers followed by X and one of a specific character.

`\d+X[!l1IL]`

so i can find 2x! oder 22x1

but if there is a >> in front, i dont want it.
i tryed to do negativ lookbehind like

`(?<!>>)\d+X[!l1IL]`

and it worked if i have a single digit number in front of the X like >>2X1
but it stoped workin if there are multiple digit numbers in between like >>222X1 and i dont get why.

Comment: You need either `(?<!>>)\b\d+X[!l1IL]` or `(?<!>>)(?<!\d)\d+X[!l1IL]`

Comment: For >>222X1 it will match 22X1 which is preceded by 2 not >>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions depending on what match boundaries you have and also depending on regex flavor:

```php
\b(?<!>>)\d+X[!l1IL]
(?<!>>|\d)\d+X[!l1IL]
(?<!>>)(?<!\d)\d+X[!l1IL]
```

The regexps mean

- `\b(?<!>>)` - match a word boundary and then make sure there is no `>>` immediately to the left of the current position
- `(?<!>>|\d)` - immediately to the left, there must be no `>>` and any digit
- `(?<!>>)(?<!\d)` - the same as above, but the lookbehind is split into two since the lengths of the alternatives differ.